# Different on click action depends on object property

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, onclick, listener

Lets say I have an object that has *isValid* property. I want to attach on click listener that do the action depends on that property, so if *ifValid* is true I want to show dialog fragment otherwise just revert it.

What is the most efficent way to do that. I'm using lambda to set the listener when initialize adapter in my activity.

```
class ItemListAdapter(..., val listener: (Item, Int) -> Unit): ...
```

ViewHolder:

```
fun bind(item: Item){
       binding.validBtn.setOnClickListener{ listener(item, adapterPosition) }
}
```

Then in my activity

```
listAdapter = ItemListAdapter() { item, _ ->
            confirm(item)
        }
```

Can I just make if statement in activity and check if item is valid like:

```
listAdapter = ItemListAdapter() { item, _ ->
            if(item.isValid!!)
            confirm(item)
            // else another action
        }
```

Comment: Why not `if (item.isValid == true) {  listener(item, adapterPosition) }` in the adapter?

Comment: Cause i want to perform different action if not valid